# Action could not be found in Rspec test for nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I am trying to get a handle on how nested routes work with Rspec. I have one of these:

```
class SupportController < ResourceController
   # stuff happens

   def support_override
      customer = Customer.find_by_id(params[:id])
      customer.override( params[:override_key] )
      redirect_to("support")
   end
 end
```

We have a route:

```
resources :support do 
  member do
    # loads of paths

    get  'support_override/:override_key' => 'support#support_override' 
  end
end
```

And the route passes a test:

```
it "should route GET support/1/support_override/ABCDEF to suport#support_override" do
  { get: '/support/1/support_override/ABCDEF'}.should route_to(controller: 'support', action: 'support_override', id: '1', override_key: 'ABCDEF' )
  end
```

However when I try to test the logic in rspec:

```
describe SupportController do
   # various levels of context and FactoryGirl calls

   it "can reach override url" do
     get :support_override, { :id=> @customer.id, :override_key="123" }
     response.should redirect_to("support")
     end

end
```

I get the following response:

> Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
>       AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
>         The action 'support_override' could not be found for SupportController

I have no doubt that the problem is with my understanding of how rspec works with nested routes, but I can't see any way to figure out what path Rspec is actually seeking and consequently it's hard to know what I need to change and I'm having trouble locating the relevant documentation.

Is there a way to find what path is being created by the test or can anyone offer guidance on how exactly the path creation works in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you haven't shared the complete `SupportController` code, I cannot pin-point exact error. BUT there are two possibilities:

1. You have defined `support_override` under `private`/`protected` by mistake.
2. You have closed the class `SupportController` before `support_override` method definition, by mistake

Your action must always be `public` so that its accessible.

Comment: You are a freaking genius, it was in the `protected` region of the class.

Comment: So the `ActionNotFound` error is an indication that it has reached the right Controller but not found the Action. I guess I should probably read my error messages properly.

Comment: Yup. That's what it means. Your action must always be `public` so that its accessible. Glad to help :)